# Print data after dumper

Tags: perl, data-dumper

I have this structure with data-dumper:

```
$VAR1 = {
      'field' => [
                 {
                   'content' => {
                                'en' => [
                                        'Footware haberdashery leather goods'
                                      ],
                                'de' => [
                                        'Schuhe Kurzwaren und Lederartikel'
                                      ],
                                'it' => [
                                        'Calzature mercerie e pelletterie'
                                      ]
                              },
                   'type' => 'tag',
                   'valore' => 'TAG3'
                 },
                 {
                   'content' => {
                                'en' => [
                                        'Cobbler'
                                      ],
                                'de' => [
                                        'Schuster'
                                      ],
                                'it' => [
                                        'Calzolai'
                                      ]
                              },
                   'type' => 'tag',
                   'valore' => 'TAG24'
                 }
               ]
    };
```

My question is: how to take data and print one for one ?
I want print the name, the tag and valore.
For my software is necessary take the name of shop and more data  for example the type

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to know how to access the values in your data structure. You want to iterate over the _field_ array reference and access keys inside the hash refs that are the elements of _field_. I suggest you read [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) and [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) for an introduction to data structures in Perl.

Comment: Does this data originate as XML? How are you generating it?

Comment: There is no name field. Do you mean content? How do you want to handle  a language with an empty array? How do you want to handle a language with more than one element in the array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the structure is a hashref containing an arrayref of hashes, and so on. And apparently where you mention 'name' you mean 'content' by language.  Likewise, it seems that where you mention 'tag' you mean 'type'. My answer will be based on those assumptions.

```
foreach my $rec (@{$href->{field}}) {
    print "$rec->{content}->{en}->[0]: $rec->{type}, $rec->{valore}\n";
}
```

The `->` between `{content}` and `{en}`, and again between `{en}` and `[0]` are optional, and a matter of style.

If you simply want to access elements directly (foregoing the loop), you might do it like this:

```
print $href->{field}->[0]->{content}->{en}->[0], "\n";
print $href->{field}->[0]->{type}, "\n";
print $href->{field}->[0]->{valore}, "\n";
```

If you want to print *all* the languages, you could do this:

```
foreach my $rec (@{$href->{field}}) {
    print $rec->{content}->{$_}->[0], "\n" foreach sort keys %{$rec->{content}};
    print $rec->{type}, "\n";
    print $rec->{valor}, "\n\n";
}
```

There are several Perl documentation pages that could be of use to you in the future as you learn to manipulate references and datastructures with Perl:  `perlreftut`, `perlref`, and `perldsc`.  Access them from your own system as `perldoc perlreftut`, for example.